# AWK sum all values of a column keeping all floats

Tags: awk, floating-point, sum, printf

I'm using the following code to grep the lines that im interested in, keep only the last ones and sum over column nine:

```
grep -n -49 'FINAL BlaBla' output |tail -9 | awk 'BEGIN {SUM=0}; {SUM=SUM+$9}; END {printf "%.3f\n" SUM}.
```

However the sum over column 9 returns 0,000

the selected lines look as follows

```
84-    C    -3.42056726    +1    -0.82831327    +1    1.52743549    +1    0.5647
85-    N    -4.78612760    +1    -1.01185554    +1    1.58894854    +1   -0.5837
86-    C    -5.19047197    +1    -2.20130686    +1    2.06176295    +1    0.3890
87-    N    -4.42537785    +1    -3.22689397    +1    2.47304603    +1   -0.4775
88-    C    -3.03532546    +1    -2.98933854    +1    2.38795560    +1    0.3686
89-    N    -2.51737448    +1    -1.78267672    +1    1.92262528    +1   -0.5526
90-   Cl    -6.86455806    +1    -2.45050886    +1    2.15229544    +1    0.0934
91-    N    -2.24043582    +1    -3.93651444    +1    2.76082642    +1    0.0890
92-    N    -2.94053526    +1     0.36941710    +1    1.06455738    +1   -0.3274
```

I can't find out where the mistake is.

I also tried to sum over $1 and I correctly obtain 792,000 but when I sum over $3 I get 31,000 ...

what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the missing comma in your `printf` expression:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {SUM=0}; {SUM=SUM+$9}; END {printf "%.3f\n", SUM}' file
#                                                       ^ 
#                                                     comma!
-0.436
```

Note by the way that there is no need to set the variable to zero, since this is the default. So drop the `BEGIN {}` block and leave to just:

```
awk '{sum+=$9}; END {printf "%.3f\n", sum}' file
```

For the other fields:

```
$ awk '{sum+=$nvar}; END {printf "%.3f\n", sum}' nvar=1 file
792.000
$ awk '{sum+=$nvar}; END {printf "%.3f\n", sum}' nvar=3 file
-35.421
$ awk '{sum+=$nvar}; END {printf "%.3f\n", sum}' nvar=9 file
-0.436
```

---

#### Why wasn't it working?

From [The GNU Awk user's guide 5.5.1 Introduction to the printf Statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html#Basic-Printf):

> A simple printf statement looks like this:
>
> ```
> printf format, item1, item2, …
> ```
>
> As for print, the entire list of arguments may optionally be enclosed
>   in parentheses
>
> The difference between printf and print is the format argument. This
>   is an expression whose value is taken as a string; it specifies how to
>   output each of the other arguments. It is called the format string.
>
> The format string is very similar to that in the ISO C library
>   function printf(). Most of format is text to output verbatim.
>   Scattered among this text are format specifiers—one per item. Each
>   format specifier says to output the next item in the argument list at
>   that place in the format.

So if you don't use commas to call the fields you get this error:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.3f" 3}'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
    `%.3f3'
       ^ ran out for this one
```

Using them it works!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.3f", 3}'
3.000
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the comma is needed. And what the difference is between `printf "xyz" "123"` and `printf "xyz", "123"`

Comment: @andlrc it is required. See my update with examples and references.

Comment: So arguments to `printf` are separated by comma while you can concatenate if it's omitted: `"hello" "world" == "helloworld"`

Comment: @andlrc `awk` has two print methods: `print` and `printf`. Both require commas in between arguments, but `printf` has a first argument to specify the format. `print` uses IFS to know what is the separator in between fields. And yes, if you don't use commas they go together: compare `awk 'BEGIN {print 3, 4}'` with `awk 'BEGIN {print 3 4}'`.

Comment: @EdMorton agreed. I am trying to get to know what is happening, but the OP seems not to follow a logical Q&update approach but, instead, a Q&A1&A2 answering over and over again with more info.